# Update specific data in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I am working on a vocable trainer written in python and using a SQLite database.
I have a function where the user can change existing vocables. With the following sqlite syntax I can choose a specific row, in this case row 8 from table Table_1

```
SELECT * FROM 'Table_1' LIMIT 1 OFFSET '8';
```

The only way I knwo to update rows is the following:

```
UPDATE 'Table_1' SET answer='bla' WHERE question='blub';
```

I do not store the ID number of the vocable in a column, I just store question, answer, phase, next_day. Is it possible to update a sepecific row without using this WHERE question 'blub' syntax but using a syntax like:

```
UPDATE 'Table_1' SET answer='bla' WHERE LIMIT 1 OFFSET '8';
```

This one is actually not working, but I guess you know what I mean.

Comment: This is exactly why we have primary keys.

Comment: To expand @Daniel's comment - A primary key uniquely identifies a row. Any other has the possibility of updating more than one row, _depending upon the data, which your code cannot absolutely control_. In most databases you can enforce uniqueness on a non-PK column with indexes, for example `question` in your case. Syntax like `LIMIT 1 OFFSET '8'` is non-standard and will get you into trouble. It may be required to solve specific problems, but should never be first choice for standard actions.

Comment: At the very least, `SELECT * FROM 'Table_1' LIMIT 1 OFFSET '8';` needs to have an `ORDER BY` clause.  Without that, it's not guaranteed that the same result will be returned even if the table never changes.